# What files to move if I want a clean slate?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

The Stanley Parable is a single-save game that lasts roughly 20 minutes. Then it loops. However, each play-through is subtly different, depending on the choices and paths you took in earlier play-throughs. This leads to a lot of in-jokes and references to things the player has experienced before.

I'd love have some friends try the game, but I'd want them to experience a fresh save. Does anyone know what files and/or folders contain the player's choices? I could move to a temporary location to have them try it fresh. Then presumably move them back after they're done.

Comment: Does it really differ based on which paths you took earlier? I remember the game being completely the same, it was just based on your decisions during a specific run.

Comment: @ChaseC I can think of several instances where small details were different from run-to-run, and that the narrator would reference previous runs, even after resets.

Comment: Added my findings on this subject in the other question, not to get the information spread out.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Excellent, thank you. I'll most likely delete this question now that there's a solid answer in the other.

Comment: Make it a duplicate, your wording is different so someone looking for this will have a better chance at getting to the information.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Fair enough, good call.